# Get a value from a field from one column if meets criteria from another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, chart, google-chart

I'm looking for a "get if" solution.

I have a list called 'Months' with two columns:

```
Month Value
1      5
2      7
3      3
```

'Value' is a Lookup (Count Related) column if it matters.

so if it's Jan, set var to 5, if Feb set var to 7 and if Mar set var to 3 and so on.

I'm struggling with the code and so far I can't manage to read any data from any list and I tried various approaches. I want to pass those values to Google charts.

I'm on SharePoint online.